# How to get a value from a Non-Public member in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, jira

I am trying to access the name of a Sprint of a Jira Issue. The custom field sprint is null but the value I need exists in the Non-Public members. I am interested in accessing the name of the Sprint. I have tried to use Reflection, but I am probably doing something wrong because I always get null.

[image]

Can someone please help me? Thank you a lot!

Update:

What I have tried so far:

`var sprint = issue.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(field => field.Id == customFieldMapping.SprintNameId)?.Values?.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType().Attributes;`

`var sprint = issue.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(field => field.Id == customFieldMapping.SprintNameId)?.Values?.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic);`

`var sprint = issue.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(field => field.Id == customFieldMapping.SprintNameId)?.Values?.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic);`

`var sprint = issue.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(field => field.Id == customFieldMapping.SprintNameId)?.Values?.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType().GetMembers(BindingFlags.NonPublic);`

`var sprint = issue.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(field => field.Id == customFieldMapping.SprintNameId)?.Values?.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType().CustomAttributes;`

All these return null.

[image]

And this is what .GetType() returns

[image]

Comment: You absolutely need to use reflection. and you should show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Thank you @JonasH . I just updated the question with what I have tried so far.

Comment: Start by breaking apart the statements into individual parts. That way you can see what part returns null, I would venture that it is not the reflection parts of your code. Also note that `GetFields` etc returns `FieldInfo[]`, i.e. a description of the field of a type, you will need to do more work to access the value and any sub-properties of the value.

Comment: @JonasH You were right. `var sprint = issue.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(field => field.Id == customFieldMapping.SprintNameId)?.Values?.FirstOrDefault()` will always give null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked for me:

`var sprint = issue.CustomFields.GetAs<JArray>("Sprint");`

`var sprintName = sprint.FirstOrDefault()?.Value<JToken>("name").ToString();`

Source: https://searchcode.com/file/128952287/Atlassian.Jira/CustomFieldValueCollection.cs/